# Divided difference and polynomial.

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

**Theorem:** If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$, then all of the divided differences $f[x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_i]$ is zero for $i\geq n+1$.

This can be proved by using the result that $f[x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_i]=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}$ for some $c\in (a,b)$, for $n$th continuously differentiable function $f$ on $[a,b]$.

Now I want to know the converse of above theorem . **Can I say that if $f$ is $n$-times continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ having all of the divided differences $f[x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_i]$ is zero for $i\geq n+1$ then $f$ must be polynomial of degree $\leq n$?**

According me converse is true as $f[x_0,x_1,\cdots, x_i]=\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}=0$ for some $c$ will give $n$th derivative of $f$ as zero as $c$ varies according $x_i$ and hence $f$ must be a polynomial. Am I right ? Please comment. Thank you.

Comment: What about $f(t) = (t-c)^n + \mathrm{e}^{-1/(t-c)^2}$? Your statement is certainly true for analytic functions $f$ but not in the stranger world of smooth non-analytic functions.

Comment: @Nicolas        $c$ is not fixed, I will changes accordingly with interpolating  points $x_i$.

Comment: Do you mean that $\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}=0$ for all $c\in\mathbb{R}$?
EDIT: You've edited your question meanwhile. So $c=x_i$? or is a smooth function of $x_i$?

Comment: @Nicolas for  different $x_i$  $c$ may be different.

Comment: @Nicolas I want to say that $c$ depends on $ x_0, x_1, \cdots x_n$

Comment: Without any further precision, it is difficult to say anything else... Perhaps someone could provide an answer if you told about the interpolation method you are using. If the range of $c$ (as a function of $(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$) is finite then you can easily arrange my counter-example above.

Comment: What about $f(t) = (t-c)^n + \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{1}{\chi(t)^2}}$ if $t\in\mathrm{Supp\,}(\chi)$ and $f(t) = (t-c)^n$ elsewhere? Here $\chi\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{R},[0,1])$ has support outside the range of $c$ - this assumes that the range of $c$ is bounded.

Comment: Notice however that the restriction of the above $f$ over the range of $c$ is polynomial; perhaps this more precise statement is true.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer is yes. Suppose $f \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R}$ and that
$$f[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n + 1}] = 0$$
for any set of distinct points $\{x_0, x_1, \dots, x_{n + 1}\} \subseteq [a, b]$.
Choose $n$ distinct points $x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n$ in $[a, b]$. Let
$$p_n(x) = \sum_{i = 0}^{n}f[x_0, \dots, x_i](x - x_0) \dots (x - x_{i - 1})$$
be the interpolation polynomial for $f$ through $x_0, \dots, x_n$.
Now fix an arbitrary $c \in [a, b]$. We can add $c$ to our list of interpolation points to get a polynomial $p_{n + 1}$ that matches $f$ at $x_0, x_1, \dots, c$. Thus
$$f(c) = p_{n + 1}(c) = p_n(c) + f[x_0, x_1, \dots, x_n, c](x - x_0)(x - x_1) \dots (x - x_n) = p_n(c).$$
Thus $f(x) = p_n(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b]$.